ассемблер, выход за пределы памяти
На заочном нежданно негаданно наступила пора ассемблера, 0 идей как и что можно подправить, дабы ошибка выход за пределы памяти прошла, помогите, пожалуйста

ORG 09f0
MVI D, 255
LXI H, 0A00
MVI A, 98
m2:
MOV M, A
DCR D
JZ m1
INX H
JMP m2
m1:
HLT 


@CrazyElf извиняюсь, поправил

Если мои смутные воспоминания об архитектуре i8080 меня не подводят, адреса должны храниться в регистровых парах (например HL), регистр H сам по себе 8-битный, туда вообще нельзя по идее записать шестнадцатибитное число 0A00

@insolor команда LXI вроде это и делает, просто в запись одно H. Сейчас попробовал прописать HL целиком, проблема осталась, программа останавливается на том же этапе :(

только сейчас заметил, что пишу mvi, d 255, а эмулятор почему фиксирует просто 55, и затык программы как раз на соответствующей позиции, почему так происходит?

А всё-таки сегмент памяти не нужно разве как-то описывать в коде? Ну то есть вот эту область с адресом 0A00 куда вы записываете, если я правильно понял. Если описания как сегмента данных нет, может оно думает, что туда нельзя писать. Вдруг там дальше код тоже, а не данные.

@CrazyElf, это не x86 архитектура, а что-то типа i8080 или i8085, там нет сегментов

@Blamy, я подозреваю, что 255 считает шестнадцтеричным значением. Попробуйте заменить на FF. По отладчику похоже, что как раз до 0A55 доходит (до этого адреса 98 записывается). Но по идее штатно должно завершиться, не понятно, почему выход за границы памяти вылетает.

@insolor большое спасибо, сработало! Добавите, как ответ на вопрос?

Я думаю лучше, если вы добавите ответ. Это же вы заметили, что 255 превращается в 55, это половина решения уже.
